# In the proof of Cauchy Integral Theorem, transforming $dz$ to polar coordinates drops $dr$ term, why?

Tags: cauchy-integral-formula

The proof on Wikipedia and the textbook both parameterize $z=x+iy$ in polar coordinates around the singularity as, $z=z_0 + re^{i\theta}$, and so I believe that $dz=e^{i\theta}dr + ire^{i\theta}d\theta$, but they make no mention of dropping the $dr$ term in the infinitesimal.
Then the contour integral, of $\oint \frac{f(z_0+re^{i\theta})}{re^{i\theta}}dz$ around the singularity $z_0$ would have a $dr$ term, not mentioned in my reading.
Please help me make sense of the $dr$ term missing, and also* explaining how it is justified to take $r\to 0$ before the $\theta$-integration is executed.

*edited

Comment: $dz= ire^{i\theta}d\theta$ and $z_0$ is the center of the arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $z_{0}$ and $r$ are constant, the only variable is the $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, and this describes the path along the circle.

Comment: $r$ is constant for the line integral, and so the term in the integrand of the arbitrary holomorphic function $f(z)=f(z_0+re^{i\theta})$, $r$, corresponds to the path of the integral, but the proof seems like it says $r$ is arbitrary and not corresponding to anything other than zero.

Comment: I don't follow? The radius of the circle is fixed here.

Comment: But to complete the theorem $f(z)\to f(z_0)$?